# listing of files in a directory

Tags: bash, sed, awk, gawk

I need to list all the files in a directory like:

```
/home/rk/a.root /home/rk/b.root /home/rk/c.root
```

for that I am using

```
$ls | gawk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}{print "/home/rk/"$1}'
```

But in that directory there are 2000 files and I need to list first 100 in one line then next 100 in next line and so on.

Also, Before each line I need to add a line "hadd result.root"

Comment: [never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Put every file in an awk-array and then add a modulo counter together with printf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
find /home/rk -type f |xargs -n100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` instead of `print` to prevent automatically adding newlines. Then declare a counter variable in the `BEGIN{ }` section, increment it for every file and if that (counter % 100) == 0 print a newline and/or the per-line requisite.